# Javascript adding dynamic a tag to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following javascript

```
d3.select(".chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("div")
      .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

and it's creating a bar chart with the data in the `data` variable. Currently (I think) it is taking each data, creating a div around it, styling it with the width and appending the text. Looking through the web dev console it seems something like this

```
<div style="width: 244.579px;">29.29</div>
<div style="width: 273.875px;">32,45</div>
....
```

The amount of divs is equal to however long the `data` array is.

On the view page, I have listed out the actual data in a bunch of divs, and each div has an anchor ready to be appended like this

```
<div id = 'anchor_1'>DATA from data[0]</div>
<div id = 'anchor_2'>DATA from data[1]</div>
....
```

I am new to javascript, but is there a way to tweak the javascript above so that it will dynamically append an `a` tag to each of the `div` above generated with the script so it'll look like

```
<div style="width: 244.579px;"><a href='#anchor_1'>29.29</a></div>
<div style="width: 273.875px;"><a href='#anchor_2'>32,45</a></div>
....
```

for all divs generated? I know how to create a loop in javascript, but I'm lost as to how to actually achieve what I want above.

Comment: Can you set a class name to these divs? i.e it becomes `<div class="foo" id = 'anchor_1'>DATA from data[0]</div>`??

Comment: I can indeed add `class foo` to every div. Will that make solving this problem easier?

Comment: not easier, it's the same except that you have to understand that you need a certain way to pick these divs *ONLY* so you won't add `a` tags to other divs by mistake

Comment: That makes sense. I'm trying the answer below to see if it works. I've tried similar approaches but I think d3 has specific order of operations that I must follow.

Comment: if you can add a class, say `bar`, then the answer below by @KashyapMukkamala will work if you replace this `document.getElementsByTagName('div');` with this `document.getElementsByClassName('bar');` and it'll will accurately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to select all the elements on you page and loop over them, you need to differentiate how the generated elements are different from the rest of the elements on you page, once you do, rest is pretty easy, just add an anchor tag dynamically while looping over:

```
var anchors = ["a1", "a2"]; // assuming you have these

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#d3-container div') // this needs to change based on how you want to select the generated elements

for(var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
  var text = divs[i].innerText;

  divs[i].innerHTML = '<a href='+anchors[i]+' >'+text+'</a>'
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6KHNUBAoV5OP4Ui2UfCA?p=preview

**EDIT:** Updated answer based on the comments

Comment: You can't just grab *ALL* divs!!!!!, you need to call them by `getElementsByClassName('someClass')` or with `.querySelectorAll('#container div')`

Comment: I have mentioned that in the answer, read through the answer and the comment in the code as well.

Comment: I've read it already, but this couldn't be the answer if he has other `div`, which in most major cases, is true.

Comment: Nice works,  +1, also the OP just replied and said he can assign a class name to these divs

Answer (score 0):

A D3 only approach:

```
d3.select(".chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("div")
      .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
      .append("a")
      .attr("xlink:href","http://www.stackoverflow.com")  
      .append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```